# Unable to add an address to a Contact via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I can create a Contact via Google Apps Script, and add a phone number but I've been unable to add an address, getting an error "The resource you requested could not be located."

Note: fName, actualLastName, email, address & phone1 are all strings

```
//  create the Contact
var newContact = ContactsApp.createContact(fName, actualLastName, email);
var newName = newContact.getFullName();
Logger.log("newName: " + newName);
Logger.log("New contact added");



//  attempt to add the address - DOESN'T WORK
try {
  Logger.log("Wanting to add this address: ", address);
  newContact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS, address);  
  Logger.log("Address added");
} catch(err) {
  Logger.log("Stumbled while trying to add address: " + err.message);
  Browser.msgBox("Stumbled while trying to add address to contact");
}
```

The logged error message is: "Info  Stumbled while trying to add address: The resource you requested could not be located."

Adding a phone number works fine:

```
newContact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, phone1);
```

And the Contact gets added to the appropriate Group:

```
var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
group.addContact(newContact);
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct workaround of your issue, for example, the method of the comment in this thread is useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64200243/7108653

Comment: OMG it worked! Please post that as an answer and I'll upvote it and mark as the solution. I gave up on this like a year ago and have been manually adding addresses since then! You've got no idea what a relief this is. Should it be filed as a bug with Google? –

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I thought that this might be also useful for other users. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, I had not checked this situation at the issue tracker. If you cannot find this issue at the issue tracker, I would like to propose to report it.

Comment: It is indeed. I've added a comment to your Answer.

Comment: Hi, I cannot reproduce this behaviour. I'm not getting any error when using your original code. Are you still experiencing this?

Comment: @lamblichus Bizarrely enough it seems to be working for me now with the ID call. I'll check further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one workaround, I would like to propose the following modification. In this modification, the contact ID is retrieved when the contact is created. And, `addPhone` and `addAddress` are used for the contact object retrieving with the contact ID.

#### Modified script:

```
var newContact = ContactsApp.createContact(fName, actualLastName, email);
var contactId = newContact.getId();
var c = ContactsApp.getContactById(contactId);
c.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS, address);
```

#### Reference:

- [getContactById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactbyidid)

Comment: It's reported, with the same/similar workaround on Google Issues Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136104507

Comment: @MrGreggles Thank you for checking it. I checked the start button.